# How to trigger scheduled server side events from an ASP page

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp (or aspx) page, it can get weather from webservice, and then send email or sms to me. But it is a web page, only when people visit, It will be activated. so I need a timer to scheduling to invoke it every day.
the code in the website hosting, so can't write winform, console application and windows service in the website hosting. How to achieve my request, google app can do it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Some hosters allow (1) windows scheduled job. (not in that list of 3 you gave). Use it to call your web page.
2. Some hosters allow SQL Agent jobs. Call the page from that.
3. Failing that, have a service/task/job running on an off hosting server that triggers it. (eg cron on your router, windows server)